# Android studio with api.ai lib

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dialogflow-es

I trying to use api.ai in a android project. So I download the Android Studio 2.3.3 create a new blank project to use android 5.0 o higher so I go [here](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client) and put the dependencies

```
compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
// api.ai SDK dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

But only to put the dependencies I got the error:

> Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'ChefBot' may be using a version of the
>   Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
>   'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade
>   plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
>
> The project
>   'ChefBot' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the
>   method. Open Gradle wrapper
>   file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

How can I fix this?

this is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' // put this and don`t work
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Where did you put those two lines? In the dependencies block? Have you applied the android plugin?

Comment: I edit with my build.gradle